# Whittaker–Shannon (sinc) interpolation in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I am using [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) from Scipy to interpolate a function with `linear` interpolation. Now I need to upgrade to [Whittaker–Shannon interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula). Is this already implemented somewhere? I am surprised it is not among the options of `interp1d` as it is a very common interpolation algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with sinc interpolation, but based on [What's wrong with this Whittaker-Shannon-Kotel’nikov interpolation implementation?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54942/whats-wrong-with-this-whittaker-shannon-kotel-nikov-interpolation-implementatio) I roughly follow the same pattern

The idea is we need to resample the original data with less frequency than the original (which is represented by `freq_s_ratio`), then reconstruct the signal using sinc, and finally resample back to the original size

However, this caused boundary artifacts, but padding and truncate signal seems to be working. Here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rough_sinc_interp(samples, freq_s_ratio = 0.5):
    offset_amount = int(len(samples)/2)
    padded_samples = np.concatenate([ offset_amount*[samples[0]], samples, offset_amount*[samples[-1]]])
    f_s = int(freq_s_ratio * len(padded_samples))
    resamples = scipy.signal.resample(padded_samples, f_s)
    T_s = 1/f_s
    t = np.arange(0, 1, T_s)
    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    for k in range(1, len(resamples)):
        y = y + resamples[k] * np.sinc((t - k*T_s)/T_s)
    return scipy.signal.resample(y, len(padded_samples))[offset_amount:-offset_amount]

np.random.seed(1337)
signal_fn = lambda x: -1*(np.sin(x) + np.cos(x**2) + np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(x)) + np.log(np.abs(x**2) + 0.1)) + 50
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.05)
y = signal_fn(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.plot(x, y, label="noisy")
plt.plot(x, rough_sinc_interp(y, freq_s_ratio=0.5), label="smooth - 50%")
plt.plot(x, rough_sinc_interp(y, freq_s_ratio=0.15), label="smooth - 15%")
plt.plot(x, rough_sinc_interp(y, freq_s_ratio=0.1), label="smooth - 10%")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample interpolated signal]

Answer (score 0):

see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/fschwar4/eb462151da065178144d53fe65e8c9fc) for a fast implementation.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def sinc_interpolation(x: NDArray, s: NDArray, u: NDArray) -> NDArray:
            """Whittaker–Shannon or sinc or bandlimited interpolation.
            Args:
                x (NDArray): signal to be interpolated, can be 1D or 2D
                s (NDArray): time points of x (*s* for *samples*) 
                u (NDArray): time points of y (*u* for *upsampled*)
            Returns:
                NDArray: interpolated signal at time points *u*
            Reference:
                This code is based on https://gist.github.com/endolith/1297227
                and the comments therein.
            TODO:
                * implement FFT based interpolation for speed up
            """
            sinc_ = np.sinc((u - s[:, None])/(s[1]-s[0]))

            return np.dot(x, sinc_)
```